# How to detect changes in a user's gallery while app is in the background - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, react-native

My goal is to detect changes in a user's gallery and implement some actions while the app runs in the background (without the app being active at all).
For now, the code below was implemented but the actions I want to perform are only available to execute while the app is active.

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {
    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
      debugPrint("gallery changed")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm almost thinking of voting to close, but maybe I'm missing something because of the vagueness of what you *actually* want. Basically *why* do you *need* your app to know what's changed in `PHPhotoLibrary` at all times?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Stéphane in iOS - No. only in Android